# Select row in tableView programmatically by other method beside calling their indexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

How can I call row in tableView by using other method beside using `[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]` method?

For example, every row in tableView has their own "action key" that detect from XML. So, i want to select the row in tableVIew programmatically by using this "action key" instead of using indexPath method.

I already search on SO but all the method are calling their indexPath.
Anybody have any idea?

These are the method that I currently used for my app to select row in tableView:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated;{
    NSLog(@"viewDidAppear");
    [super viewDidAppear:YES];

    // saving an NSString
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *action_app = [defaults objectForKey:@"app"];
    [defaults setObject:@"closed_NewVC" forKey:@"closed_NewVC"];

    //will select row in tableView when receive key action from Push Notification
    if (([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"app"] isEqualToString:@"a1"]) && ([AryStoreInboxItem count]>0)){

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
        [self->tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
        [self tableView:self->tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    }else if (([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"app"] isEqualToString:@"a2"]) && ([AryStoreInboxItem count]>1)){

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0];
        [self->tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
        [self tableView:self->tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    }else if (([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"app"] isEqualToString:@"a3"]) && ([AryStoreInboxItem count]>2)){

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:0];
        [self->tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
        [self tableView:self->tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    }else if (([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"app"] isEqualToString:@"a4"]) && ([AryStoreInboxItem count]>3)){

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:3 inSection:0];
        [self->tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
        [self tableView:self->tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    }else if (([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"app"] isEqualToString:@"a5"]) && ([AryStoreInboxItem count]>4)){

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:4 inSection:0];
        [self->tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
        [self tableView:self->tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    }else if (([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"app"] isEqualToString:@"a6"]) && ([AryStoreInboxItem count]>5)){

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:5 inSection:0];
        [self->tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
        [self tableView:self->tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    }else if (([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"app"] isEqualToString:@"a7"]) && ([AryStoreInboxItem count]>6)){

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:6 inSection:0];
        [self->tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
        [self tableView:self->tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    }else if (([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"app"] isEqualToString:@"a8"]) && ([AryStoreInboxItem count]>7)){

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:7 inSection:0];
        [self->tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
        [self tableView:self->tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    }else if (([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"app"] isEqualToString:@"d1"]) && ([AryStoreInboxItem count]>8)){

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:8 inSection:0];
        [self->tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
        [self tableView:self->tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    }else if (([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"app"] isEqualToString:@"e1"]) && ([AryStoreInboxItem count]>9)){

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:9 inSection:0];
        [self->tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
        [self tableView:self->tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    }else if (([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"app"] isEqualToString:@"m11"]) && ([AryStoreInboxItem count]>10)){

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:10 inSection:0];
        [self->tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
        [self tableView:self->tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    }else if (([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"app"] isEqualToString:@"m12"]) && ([AryStoreInboxItem count]>11)){

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:11 inSection:0];
        [self->tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
        [self tableView:self->tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    }else if (([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"app"] isEqualToString:@"b1"]) && ([AryStoreInboxItem count]>12)){

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:12 inSection:0];
        [self->tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
        [self tableView:self->tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    }else if (([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"app"] isEqualToString:@"b2"]) && ([AryStoreInboxItem count]>13)){

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:13 inSection:0];
        [self->tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
        [self tableView:self->tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    }else if (([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"app"] isEqualToString:@"b3"]) && ([AryStoreInboxItem count]>14)){

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:14 inSection:0];
        [self->tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
        [self tableView:self->tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    }else if (([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"app"] isEqualToString:@"b4"]) && ([AryStoreInboxItem count]>15)){

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:15 inSection:0];
        [self->tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
        [self tableView:self->tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    }else if (([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"app"] isEqualToString:@"b5"]) && ([AryStoreInboxItem count]>16)){

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:16 inSection:0];
        [self->tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
        [self tableView:self->tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    }else if (([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"app"] isEqualToString:@"b6"]) && ([AryStoreInboxItem count]>17)){

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:17 inSection:0];
        [self->tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
        [self tableView:self->tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    }else if (([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"app"] isEqualToString:@"b7"]) && ([AryStoreInboxItem count]>18)){

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:18 inSection:0];
        [self->tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
        [self tableView:self->tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    }else if (([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"app"] isEqualToString:@"b8"]) && ([AryStoreInboxItem count]>19)){

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:19 inSection:0];
        [self->tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
        [self tableView:self->tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    }else if (([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"app"] isEqualToString:@"b9"]) && ([AryStoreInboxItem count]>20)){

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:20 inSection:0];
        [self->tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
        [self tableView:self->tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    }else if (([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"app"] isEqualToString:@"b10"]) && ([AryStoreInboxItem count]>21)){

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:21 inSection:0];
        [self->tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
        [self tableView:self->tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    }else if (([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"app"] isEqualToString:@"b11"]) && ([AryStoreInboxItem count]>22)){

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:22 inSection:0];
        [self->tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
        [self tableView:self->tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    }else{

        NSLog(@"Others key sent from Push Notification OR key/value not exist in tableView since user not update");
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"app"];
        NSLog(@" key form push has been cleared! ==> %@ ! ",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"app"] );
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you not used Switch case instead of if-else statement???

Comment: @Reformer..that was not my problem right now..that "app" key was from push notification..my problem is how to call row in tableView by using other method than what i'm using right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When dealing with a `UITableView` there's finally no advisable way to access or interact with cells without using `NSIndexPath`. So I'd recommend you to create a solid data source to determine the correct `NSIndexPath` for a single data/model object.

Comment: thank you for your explanation...it look like i already wasted a week to solve this..

Answer (score 0):

Your datasource should translate between your action key and the index path.

Ie your data source could tune in for notification broadcasted by your XML classes.